# How to make javascript http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, xmlhttprequest

I want to send http requests via pure javascript and i have searched all websites and i saw nothing but xml and ajax.is there any other ways to do so ?
If not could you please show me how to use it via xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XHR isn't just for XML... you can use it with other types of responses.

The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is a newer standard that is a bit more flexible and supports streaming.

Comment: Thanks a lot.is it possible to require an external javascript library in script html tag ?